# Extract Unique value in nested lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list with different and repeated IP Addresses. So I want to extract a unique IP Address from the nested list.
[image]

```
import re
pattern='(\d+.{13,15})'
matches =[re.findall(pattern,str(x)) for x in dfs['Task Category']]
print(matches)  

import numpy as np 
new_list = list(np.concatenate(matches)) 
print(new_list)

[['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.115.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.115.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.178.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], [], [], [], [], [], ['192.168.101.115.'], ['192.168.101.178.'], [], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.82.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.79.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.79.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.115.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.79.'], ['192.168.101.115.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.115.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.43.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], [], ['192.168.101.62.'], [], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.115.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.43.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.82.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], [], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.115.'], ['192.168.101.115.'], ['192.168.101.115.'], ['192.168.101.178.'], ['192.168.101.115.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.82.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.82.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.82.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.82.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.115.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.115.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.115.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.115.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.115.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.115.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.62.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.91.'], ['192.168.101.252.'], ['192.168.101.252.'], ['192.168.101.252.'], ['192.168.101.252.'], ['192.168.101.252.'], ['192.168.101.252.']
```

Comment: Please post codes as text rather than images so others could use them easily.

Comment: i try but i am unable to make a code to extract IP address, if you want my rough code then i Edit this post.

Comment: copy-paste the code and list of IP addresses as shown in the image to this post?

Comment: Also, ```I want to extract *a* unique IP Address from the nested list```, so you only need 1?

Comment: No, I want all unique IPs so I can test connections to a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `set` or a `Counter`:

```
set(match for x in dfs['Task Category'] for match in re.findall(pattern,str(x))
```

Or:

```
from collections import Counter

Counter(match for x in dfs['Task Category'] for match in re.findall(pattern,str(x))
```

Or, using [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas):

```
dfs['Task Category'].str.extractall(f'({pattern})')[0].unique()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell, but I guess your list is just a list of a list, so:

```
my_list = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3]] # This is my guessing of your list

unique_list = []
  
# traverse for all elements
for x in my_list:
        # check if exists in unique_list or not
        if x not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(x)
```

The Output:

```
unique_list
[[1, 2, 3]] # If you need the list inside, just: unique_list[0]
```