# How get unique pixels from 2d numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2d array with rgb pixel data (2 row with 3 pixel in a row).

```
[[[255, 255, 255],[3, 0, 2],[255, 255, 255]],[[255, 255, 255],[3, 0, 2],[255, 255, 255]]]
```

How can I get unique pixel? I want to get

```
[[255, 255, 255], [3, 0, 2]]
```

I am trying to use `np.unique` and `np.transpose` with `np.reshape` but I wasn't able to get the desired result.

Comment: is this your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73440403/extract-unique-value-in-nested-lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshape the array to 2D and then use `np.unique` with `axis=0`

```
arr = np.array([[[255, 255, 255],[3, 0, 2],[255, 255, 255]],[[255, 255, 255],[3, 0, 2],[255, 255, 255]]])
shape = arr.shape
arr = arr.reshape((shape[0] * shape[1], shape[2]))
print(np.unique(arr, axis=0))
```

Output

```
[[  3   0   2]
 [255 255 255]]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
import itertools
np.unique(np.array(list(itertools.chain(*arr))), axis=0)
```

```
array([[  3,   0,   2],
       [255, 255, 255]])
```